# Golang Changing HTTP Response Status Code 201 with Body in the Response

Tags: http, go, http-status-code-404, httpresponse

How do I set the response status code to 201 while including a JSON object in the response body? I can't seem to perform both of these at once -- either I return a 200 with a message body, or a 201 without one.

Comment: Can you include the code you're using that isn't working?

Answer (score 8):

I just tried and it seems to work.

Would you have a sample of broken code?

Simple example: (https://play.golang.org/p/xg8lGNofze)

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "log"
    "net/http"
)

func testHdlr(w http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    m := map[string]string{
        "foo": "bar",
    }
    w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)
    _ = json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(m)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", testHdlr)
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil))
}
```

Then

```
$> curl -v http://localhost:8080
[...]
< HTTP/1.1 201 Created
< Date: Thu, 25 May 2017 00:54:15 GMT
< Content-Length: 14
< Content-Type: application/json
< 
{ [14 bytes data]
* Curl_http_done: called premature == 0

100    14  100    14    0     0   2831      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  3500
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
{"foo":"bar"}
```

Comment: appears the order is critical. If one does `w.WriteHeader(http.StatusCreated)` before `w.Header().Add("Content-Type", "application/json")` - the header is lost.

Comment: https://play.golang.org/p/X7NpG4lOosi produces  `Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8`

Comment: Got stuck with this myself. The relevant documentation is at Header in the type ResponseWriter [Changing the header map after a call to WriteHeader (or Write) has no effect unless the modified headers are trailers.](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ResponseWriter.Header)